# "I never drink" "I don't either/ I do too/I never do, too"

Tags: grammar

It might seem trivial but I'm not really sure which one is grammatically correct.

To agree with a sentence with *never* we should use *too* or *either*?

> A:  I never drink.
>
> B: .............

Thanks

Comment: "I don't either."  or "Neither do I."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If someone never drinks, that means that there is never a time when they drink.  So if we say "We never drink, too", that sounds like we're saying that we also "do something", and that something is "never drink".  But there's nothing which is actually done - it's a **lack of doing something**.  So, using "too" isn't right.  So, it's grammatically correct (I think), but conceptually or logically wrong.

Say "I don't either." or "I don't, either."  (I'm not sure if it's better with or without the comma).

Comment: I'd say 'me neither', which I am sure would be entirely ungrammatical, but very common. If I was trying to be 'more proper' I might say 'Neither do I'.

Comment: I think "Me neither", "I don't either", and "Neither do I" are all perfectly fine, actually.

Comment: Well, I thought that 'neither do I' was probably okay, but suspected 'me neither' of  being the sort of usage which earn comments about native speakers not speaking the language properly. i don't know a great deal about grammar beyond 'how I speak'. :)

Comment: I actually don't know whether "Me neither" is grammatical or not, but it's certainly very common and accepted, perhaps as informal language.